# Unable to sideload a file to One Plus One. What are my alternatives?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, usb-drivers

I have a oneplus one which had CM 13 installed on it. The recovery is TWRP. Last day I tried to install Kali Nethunter ROM on the same from recovery. However things got messy and the phone didn't boot. To make things worse, I by mistake wiped everything on the device.

So I now have A device with NO OS and NO Data.

Then I booted the device to recovery and tried to use sideload. However the device wasn't getting detected on my laptop. Following commands resulted no positive results.

```
adb devices [no devices connected]
adb push [failed]
adb sideload [failed]
```

Since the device is not even getting detected as an unknown device in the USB port, I tried installing the universal adb driver available. That also didn't help.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flash the phone in fastboot mode.

1. First you need to unlock the bootloader (if it wasn't done before):

   - Power off your phone then boot into fastboot mode with **power button + volume up button**.
   - Connect your phone to your PC via usb cable.
   - Open a command prompt
   - Check your fastboot connection by issuing this command: `fastboot devices`
     *It should return your device serial number, if not you need to make sure your drivers are installed correctly*.
   - Once you've confirmed your fastboot connection issue this command:

   fastboot oem unlock

   *The device will now go through the automated unlocking process, just let it do its things*.

   - Done

     2. Flashing thee Cyanogen OS Fastboot Images
   - Download the latest stock images
   - Reboot your device into Fastboot Mode (power + volume up) and connect your phone to your PC via usb cable.
   - Unzip the file you downloaded and put its contents into your fastboot folder.
   - Open a command prompt.
   - Issue these fastboot commands (Every line ends by hitting enter):

   fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin

   fastboot flash sbl1 sbl1.mbn

   fastboot flash dbi sdi.mbn

   fastboot flash aboot emmc_appsboot.mbn

   fastboot flash rpm rpm.mbn

   fastboot flash tz tz.mbn

   fastboot flash LOGO logo.bin

   fastboot flash oppostanvbk static_nvbk.bin

   fastboot flash boot boot.img

   fastboot flash cache cache.img

   fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

   fastboot flash system system.img

   fastboot flash userdata userdata_64G.img

or

```
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
```

(if you have the 16gb model)

- Reboot your device with this command:

  fastboot reboot
- Done.

Let me know if something goea wrong.